# Searching an array for a substring in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, substring

I have searched across the web though have not had any luck in correcting my issue. What I want to do is search an array for a substring and return the result. An example of the array is like this:

```
the_array = ["PP: com.package.id, NN: Package Name","PP: com.another.id, NN: Another Name"];
```

What I want to do is search `the_array` for `com.package.id` making sure that it appears between the `"PP:"` and `","`. Also please note that the array will contain several thousand values. Hope you can help, thank you.

Comment: What did you try? All you can do is iterating over the array and examine each string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way:

`the_array.join("|").indexOf([str]) >= 0;`

Other ways would be to loop thru the array using `.each()` or a simple `for` loop

```
Array.prototype.each = function(callback){
    for (var i =  0; i < this.length; i++){
        callback(this[i]);
    }
}

the_array.each(function(elem){
    console.log(elem.indexOf('<searchString goes here>'));
});
```

Comment: `each` is not a JavaScript function.

Comment: FWIW, ECMAScript 5 introduced `forEach`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach You can also find an alternative implementation there. But it seems to me that `each` is irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: Yes and Yes. Since ES5 is not universally supported yet, we need these workarounds.

Comment: @Mrchief it is 'each.indexOf'. Please change it.

Comment: @KamalReddy: It's pseudocode, note that `[str]` is not an array but placeholder for search string in question. But I'll edit for clarity anyway.