# Loop through array and filter emails

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to filter our values from an array depending on what the users email is.

An example is, I have an array that looks like:

```
var myArray = ["nick@hotmail.com","nick@gmail.com","nick@yahoo.com","bob@hotmail.com", "bob@gmail.com", "matt@hotmail.com", "test@hotmail.com", "lay@gmail.com", "file@yahhoo.com", "terry@test.com", "rich@email.com"];
```

I am trying to push only the values that end in the following email addresses:

1. *@hotmail.com
2. *@gmail.com

I would like to filter out ALL other email addresses. So it only returns the email addresses where the addresses matches the values above.

I have come up with the following code:

```
var filteredArray = [];

for (var i = 0, l = myJson.length; i < l; i++) {
  /// Don't know what to put here!
  filteredArray.push();
}
```

I would like to push the desired values to the `filteredArray`. All the other values like: @yahhoo.com & @test.com & @email.com I do not need.

I think I am in the starting position but don't know how to loop through and filter based on part of a string. Thanks.

Comment: Um... Array has a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Comment: Maybe a regex: `if (/@(hot|g)mail[.]com$/.test(myJson[i]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`. It returns a new array with the values that would cause the callback function to return true.

```js
var myArray = ["nick@hotmail.com","nick@gmail.com","nick@yahoo.com","bob@hotmail.com", "bob@gmail.com", "matt@hotmail.com", "test@hotmail.com", "lay@gmail.com", "file@yahhoo.com", "terry@test.com", "rich@email.com"];

var filtered = myArray.filter(function(email) {
  return email.endsWith('@hotmail.com') || email.endsWith('@gmail.com');
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Worth noting, `string.endsWith()` is only compatible with the most modern browsers. You can use `string.lastIndexOf()` to do the same the thing with greater compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ES6 function [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) with the `filter` function to achieve this.

```
let fitleredEmails = myJson.filter(index => index.includes("@gmail.com") || index.includes("@hotmail.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way of reversing this ... so instead of includes it **does not include** the values; I have tried this:

`myJson.filter(index => !index.includes("@gmail.com")`

But this doesn't return anything ...have you got any ideas by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredArray = myArray.filter(function(element) {
  return element.endsWith('@hotmail.com') || element.endsWith('@gmail.com');
});
```