# Find all elements in array that contain the search key

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a built in method in Typescript that searches a string array and finds all items that contain the search string. e.g.

```
var myarray = ["apple", "orange", "app"];
var searchKey = "app"
```

this search key should return the array ["apple", "app"]

Comment: Dupe: [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Comment: There isn't a single function that just does this. But you can build it with `filter()` and `indexOf()`.