# Find partial string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var fruits = ["CarPaint.InString.Banana", "CarPaint.InString.Orange", "CarPaint.InString.Apple", "CarPaint.InString.Mango"];
var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
```

Let's say you don't know whats inside the fruits array ?

How do you extract the string that contains mango.

The prefix string must be included in the result.

Can this be done without a for loop and parsing ?

```js
    var fruits = ["CarPaint.InString.Banana", "CarPaint.InString.Orange", "CarPaint.InString.Apple", "CarPaint.InString.Mango"];
var n = fruits.includes("Mango");
console.log(n)
```

Comment: Duplicate of: [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)  And as IceMetalPunk mentions, filter still loops (or "iterates")

Comment: It can't be done without looping; there's no way to know whether a value matches your check unless you try all of them. `Array.filter` is the best way to do this, as mentioned in the answers, but please note that is still looping, since `filter` loops internally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the array and check each string.

```js
var fruits = ["CarPaint.InString.Banana", "CarPaint.InString.Orange", "CarPaint.InString.Apple", "CarPaint.InString.Mango"],
    result = fruits.filter(string => string.includes("Mango"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks nina I can accept in 12 mins

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.includes('Mango'))
// [ 'CarPaint.InString.Mango' ]
```

Comment: please see below or above ...

Comment: Looks like we came to the same answer. OP, if you see this, please accept Nina's answer and not mine.