# Get items for selected item from array

Tags: javascript

I have array like this structure

```
["12 18:00", "15 17:30","16 12:00", "12 21:30", "9 10:30"...]
```

and it has unknown number of elements. I want get every hour:minute for selected element.
Example: if ele=="12" then get 18:00, 21:30. Maybe array has more "12 16:30","12 13:00" etc elements. Then also get 16:30, 13:00. All get elements 18:00, 21:30, 16:30, 13:00

Help me for this solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? That's doable with a simple `for` loop (or `.filter()`, `.reduce()`) and `.substr()`, `.substring()`, `.slice()` (or `.split()`)

Comment: I would change the structure of your data to something like `{ "12": ["18:00", "21:30"], "15": ["17:30"], "16": ["12:00"], ...}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Comment: let arr = ['12 18:00', '13 19:00','12 21:30']
let tmp = arr.map(element => {
return element.split(" ")
})
let bool = Boolean(tmp.find(element => parseInt(element[0]) === 12))   and it is only return one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const array = ["12 18:00", "15 17:30","16 12:00", "12 21:30", "9 10:30"];
const getItems = number => {
    return array.filter(item => item.split(" ")[0] === number.toString()).map(item => item.split(" ")[1])
}
console.log(getItems(12));
```