# find object in array, to find object where id match substring

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I get a lot of arrays from API but a count of id different and I need to check for match `[id = region...]` and to get only this object. How I can do this using regular expressions and `find`?

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "address.7576869587107444", type: "Feature", place_type: Array(1), relevance: 1, properties: {…}, …}
1: {id: "postcode.12959148828066430", type: "Feature", place_type: Array(1), relevance: 1, properties: {…}, …}
2: {id: "place.14392640799224870", type: "Feature", place_type: Array(1), relevance: 1, properties: {…}, …}
3: {id: "region.9375820343691660", type: "Feature", place_type: Array(1), relevance: 1, properties: {…}, …}
4: {id: "country.13200156005766020", type: "Feature", place_type: Array(1), relevance: 1, properties: {…}, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)


.then(res => {
        let region = /region/gi
        console.log(res.data.features.find(place => place.id == region.test(place)))
        setAdrress(res.data)
      })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
console.log(res.data.features.find(place => place.id.match(region)))
```

```js
const arr = [{id: "address.7576869587107444", type: "Feature"},
{id: "postcode.12959148828066430", type: "Feature"},
{id: "place.14392640799224870", type: "Feature"},
{id: "region.9375820343691660", type: "Feature"},
{id: "country.13200156005766020", type: "Feature"}];
let region = /region/gi;
console.log(arr.find(place => place.id.match(region)))
```

Comment: @JessicaBulldog Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array and check with a regex to achieve that.

```
var regex = RegExp(/^region/);
var filtered_arr = arr.filter(obj => regex.test(obj.id));
```

`filtered_arr` will contain your array of the objects where the id starts with `region`

Using regex will ensure that all the string which **start** with `region` will be filtered. Using something like match will find the ids which have `region` anywhere in the string. I couldn't comment on the first post as I don't have enough reputation. :)