# Match the part of a string in the array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a single dimensional array with the below format,

```
let e = ["CGST:20", "SGST:20", "IGST:20", "CESS:20", "GSTIncentive:20", "GSTPCT:20"].map(i=>i.trim());
```

And want to match the specific string in the array, say for example, match the part of the string "IGST" in the "IGST:20".

I have tried in the below way, but it always matching the first key in the array,

```
if(/^IGST:/.test(e)){
  console.log("matched")
} else {
  console.log("Not matched")
}
```

Comment: *"but it always matching the first key in the array"* No, it's always matching the array's contents after they've been converted to a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -  can you please suggest better approach to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In javascript, how do you search an array for a substring match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/in-javascript-how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to find out if that regular expression matches *any* entry in the array, you can use the `some` function for that:

```
if (e.some(entry => /^IGST:/.test(entry)) {
    console.log("matched")
} else {
    console.log("Not matched")
}
```

If you want to *find* the matching entry, use `find` instead. If you want its index, use `findIndex`.

Details [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).